# How to add tooltip / hoverbox to jupyter lab extension

Tags: reactjs, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

[HoverExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAxzU.jpg)

How to add hover text like that of the above image to a custom extension in jupyterlab. I'm making an extension in jupyter lab using react, but I want to add a description of the extension in a hoverbox. However I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

To add a hover box in the extension, you have to pass value to [widgetInstance].title.caption
For example:

```
const extension: JupyterFrontEndPlugin<void> = {
  id: 'some-id',
  autoStart: true || false,
  activate: async(app: JupyterFrontEnd, palette: ICommandPalette) => {
     const { commands } = app;
      let widget1: widget= new widget(); // create the widget
      widget1.id = 'widget1-id';
      widget1.title.label = 'widget Label';
      widget1.title.caption="widget hovering text description"; // this will show the text when you hover over an extension
      app.shell.add(widget1, 'right', { rank: 1 });
      ...
      ...
      ... rest of your code ...

}
```